# Python Subprocess Error

Tags: python, software-development

I am trying to call this command:
`avconv -i '/opt/music/Smooth Criminal.mp3' -ac 1 -ar 22050 -b 352k -f wav - | /opt/pifm/bin/pifm - 98.3` with my own paths.
In the terminal it works like a charm but when I run it through the python subprocess module I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alarmclock.py", line 23, in <module>
    play_files();
  File "alarmclock.py", line 9, in play_files
    call(["sudo avconv -i '/home/pi/Files/alarm.mp3' -ac 1 -ar 22050 -b 352k -f wav - | sudo '/home/pi/Files/pifm' - 105.9"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I am sure the paths I have a real files and I know that because it works perfectly from terminal. For some reason the call method is not liking this line. I tried all sorts of combinations of quotes to make it know which were the paths, etc but I have not been able to get it to work.

From Python I am calling it like this: `call(["$"])` where $ is the above command. If I change those quotes to single quotes it gives a syntax error:
`File "alarmclock.py", line 9
    call(['avconv -i '/home/pi/Files/alarm.mp3' -ac 1 -ar 22050 -b 352k -f wav - | sudo /home/pi/Files/pifm - 89.9'])
                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I cannot see anything wrong with the syntax there.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I tried suggestion in comments bellow to to switch both but that gave the same error. Any Ideas?

Comment: Try swapping the single and double quotes- you can just change one. So in your original version of the command, it should start 'avconf ... "/home/pi/Fil....   Make sense?

Comment: I meant *can't* not *can*. Try swapping the single and double quotes- you can't just change one. So in your original version of the command, it should start 'avconf ... "/home/pi/Fil....   Make sense?

Comment: That gives the same error. :-( Any other suggestions?

Comment: Which same error? invalid syntax or no such file or directory?

Comment: Sorry, the no such file or directory error.

Comment: Ok. Now try the script with this command. "which aconv"

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do will work with subprocess, but take that with a pinch of salt becuase I've only used it once or twice.  It's your machine, you could try os.system rather than subprocess and accept all the security holes.  os.system("sudo avconv -i /home/pi/Files/alarm.mp3 -ac 1 -ar 22050 -b 352k -f wav - | sudo /home/pi/Files/pifm - 105.9")

Comment: That's what I ended up doing and it worked great! I was just wondering for the future though, why this didn't work.

Comment: What security holes?

Comment: @NULL Frankly I don't know.  It's what I'm always told when I use it but I have never been bothered enough to check.  Google will reveal all.